# How to do something while a dojo xhr request is waiting or loading

Tags: ajax, dojo

I'm relatively new to dojo, and although I've managed to do all I *need*, there are certain things I just can't figure out how to do with it.

Simply put, I have a form and when I click the submit button the request goes in fine and for the most part all is good. However, now I *want* to have in a div or some content that changes every 10 seconds or so while the user been waits for the request to go through... this is what I can't figure out how to do.

The content I want to put in the div is static, so there's no need to have a request inside another request or any madness like that, all I want is that every so often the content changes (eg say I want a div that says "You've been waiting X seconds and counting").

Hopefully anybody can give me a hand with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is strange.  dojo.xhr defaults to asynchronous calls, which means that it returns immediately, allowing you to continue with you other work.  It does not block unless you set "sync" to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution would be

1. Fire a request
2. Start a setInterval to do your stuff or show a loader gif or whatever
3. When the request returns, undo what you did in part 2.

---

```
// 1
var req = dojo.xhr( /*...*/ );

// 2 
var inter = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("waiting..."); //do stuff
}, 10000); //time in miliseconds

//3
function undo(){
    clearInterval(inter);
} 
req.then(undo, undo); //undo either on sucess or on error
```

Answer (score 7):

Exactly where Dojo shines thanks to its AOP approach, i.e. dojo.connect(). Here is the code (and also at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/5Bgtw/)):

```
dojo.require("dojox.timing");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

dojo.declare("phusick.Form", null, {

    send: function() {
        var def = dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "/echo/json/",
            content: {
                json: dojo.toJson({data: "some data"})
            },
            handleAs: "json"
        });

        def.addCallback(this, "onSendSuccess");
        this.onSend();
    },

    onSend: function() {},

    onSendSuccess: function(result) {} 
});

dojo.declare("phusick.Observer", null, {

    observe: function(form) {
        this.form = form;
        this.interval = 5;
        this.timer = new dojox.timing.Timer(this.interval);
        dojo.connect(this.timer, "onStart", this, function() {this.timeElapsed = 0});
        dojo.connect(this.timer, "onTick", this, "onTick");
        dojo.connect(form, "onSend", this.timer, "start");
        dojo.connect(form, "onSendSuccess", this.timer, "stop");
    },

    onTick: function() {
        this.timeElapsed += this.interval;
        dojo.byId("output").innerHTML = this.timeElapsed + " ms";
    }

});


dojo.ready(function() {
    var form = new phusick.Form();
    var observer = new phusick.Observer();
    observer.observe(form);

    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("sendBtn"), "onClick", function() {
        form.send();
    });

});
```

1. Class phusick.Form that calls onSend() method when XHR starts and onSendSuccess() method when XHR finishes (thanks to callback).
2. Class phusick.Observer with observe() method that requires a single parameter: instance of phusick.Form. It starts and stops timer when onSend()/onSendSuccess() of passed form is called.

Comment: I like your solution, and I'll +1 because I believe it's the best solution, however, I'll be marking the solution from @missingno as the one accepted due to how simple it is to implement with what I already have. Thanks though as I'll be using this a lot in the future.