# dojo 1.7+ timer/setInterval misunderstanding

Tags: function, time, dojo, setinterval

I have a javascript code that creates a simple clock.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/date/locale",
    "dojo/_base/event"
], 
function(declare, dom, locale, event) {
    return declare([], {
        ...
        ...
        createClock : function() {
            html_time = dom.byId("time");
            window.setInterval(this.tick(), 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

**JS code is working correctly!** Also, I have a html code:

```
<body>
    <script>
        require([ "gui/common/Clock"
        ],
        function(Clock) {
            var clock = new Clock();
            clock.createClock();
        });
    </script>
    Current time: <span id="time"></span>
    ...
```

But if I run the code in the browser, then I get an error:

```
Error: useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)
[Break On This Error]   

window.setInterval(this.tick(), 1000);
```

In the browser the time appears, but it does not tick. Anybody can explain what is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not execute the method: `window.setInterval(this.tick, 1000);`

Also to execute `tick` in `this` scope, use `lang.hitch` as of `dojo/_base/lang` module:

```
window.setInterval(lang.hitch(this, "tick"), 1000);
```

You can find some inspiration in my answer to [How to do something while a dojo xhr request is waiting or loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512483/how-to-do-something-while-a-dojo-xhr-request-is-waiting-or-loading/8515115#8515115).